# How does Gideon Malick know about Simmons?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

In *Agents of SHIELD* s03e08, Gideon Malick knows that

> Simmons went through the monolith portal, and returned with the help of SHIELD.

Malick follows up in s03e09, when he

> Kidnaps Fitz and Simmons, and interrogates them to learn how Simmons got back.

**But how would he know that she had done this?**

There don't seem to be any HYDRA spies or surveillance within SHIELD. Nobody from SHIELD has been advertising her return. Simmons has barely left the base. But Malick must know somehow – so what have I missed?

Comment: Without going back and rewatching the relevant episodes, I imagine Ros, or one of the other members of the ATCU, picked up on it during the many times they came in to contact with members of SHIELD after her return - including a tour of the SHIELD headquarters/base. Ros is in regular contact with Malick, and it seems like the kind of thing that would get mentioned.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They have May's ex-husband, Andrew. He is the source of this information.

Malik has Andrew in the S.H.I.E.L.D. containment unit, and he says he wants to know about S.H.I.E.L.D..

> What else has S.H.I.E.L.D.been up to?

Later he reveals to Ward that S.H.I.E.L.D. has done what Hydra could never accomplish.

> Send someone through the portal and bring them back again.

[image]

He is a great S.H.I.E.L.D.insider, since he has done evaluations (and probably his own observations) on all the top brass at SHIELD.

Comment: Malik knows before interrogating Andrew.

Comment: @ibid In "Many Heads, One Tail" Malik asks Andrew what else SHIELD is hiding at 25:00 (ish). He tells Grant that SHIELD did what Hydra could never do at 40:20.

Comment: I was thinking of when Ward interrogates him at the end of the episode.

Comment: I’d completely forgotten about Andrew. Thanks for reminding me.